# How to format date string via multiple formats in python

Tags: python, date, datetime, format, strptime

I have three date formats: `YYYY-MM-DD`, `DD.MM.YYYY`, `DD/MM/YYYY`.

Is it possible to validate and parse strings such as `2014-05-18` or `18.5.2014` or `18/05/2019`?

Comment: Have you looked at [dateutil](https://labix.org/python-dateutil) - failing that - just try `strptime`ing each 3 in turn to see if they work, otherwise fail...

Comment: Thank you for the comment.I want use pure python without third party libs

Answer (score 181, accepted):

Try each format and see if it works:

```
from datetime import datetime

def try_parsing_date(text):
    for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%d.%m.%Y', '%d/%m/%Y'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(text, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError('no valid date format found')
```

Comment: what if we have huge data and multiple date formats, then looping through a loop is feasible in terms of time complexity? will it not be slow?

Answer (score 55):

```
>>> import dateutil.parser
>>> dateutil.parser.parse(date_string)
```

This should take care of most of the standard date formats in Python 2.7+. If you really have super custom date formats, you can always fall back to the one mentioned by Jon Clements.

Comment: This works fine, but if the date formats are all known in advance, the solution by Jon Clements of trying each format and catching exceptions will likely be much faster.

Comment: saved me so much time, thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

This actually a problem i was facing and this how i approached it, my main purpose was to the date seperators

```
class InputRequest:
     "This class contain all inputs function that will be required in this program. "

      def __init__(self, stockTickerName = 'YHOO', stockSite='yahoo', startDate = None, 
             endDate = datetime.date.today()):

      def requestInput(self, requestType =''):
          "Fro requesting input from user"
          self.__requestInput = input(requestType)
          return self.__requestInput


def dateFormat(self, dateType=''):
    '''
        this function handles user date input
        this repeats until the correct format is supplied
        dataType: this is the type of date, eg: DOF, Date of Arriveal, etc 

    '''
    while True:
        try:
            dateString = InputRequest.requestInput(self,dateType)
            dtFormat = ('%Y/%m/%d','%Y-%m-%d','%Y.%m.%d','%Y,%m,%d','%Y\%m\%d') #you can add extra formats needed
            for i in dtFormat:
                try:
                    return datetime.datetime.strptime(dateString, i).strftime(i)
                except ValueError:
                    pass

        except ValueError:
            pass
        print('\nNo valid date format found. Try again:')
        print("Date must be seperated by either [/ - , . \] (eg: 2012/12/31 --> ): ")
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to add a bit to @jon-clements already great answer,

added some verbosity on the exception raised for traceability purposes

```
from datetime import datetime

def try_parsing_date(possible_date, field):
    """
    Try to parse a date using several formats, warn about
    problematic value if the possible_date does not match
    any of the formats tried
    """
    for fmt in ('%Y-%m-%d', '%d/%m/%Y', '%m/%d/%Y'):
        try:
            return datetime.strptime(possible_date, fmt)
        except ValueError:
            pass
    raise ValueError(f"Non-valid date format for field {field}: '{possible_date}'")
```

Here, `possible_date` is the text that may contain a date in one of the formats, and `field` would be the variable or column that you are testing. This makes it easier to find the problematic value

Answer (score -7):

Pure python:

```
from datetime import datetime
my_datetime = datetime.strptime('2014-05-18', '%Y-%m-%d') 
repr(my_datetime)

>>> 'datetime.datetime(2014,5,18,0,0)'
```

Check datetime.strptime() format documentation for more format strings.

Comment: The solution should be expanded to use all date formats and explain how to choose which one fits.

Comment: @HansThen you're right, but answer above already answers the question correctly and there's nothing to add to it.

Comment: Yes, it is hard to improve upon @Jon Clements.