# Python Regex matching any order

Tags: python, regex, datetime, match

Lets say I have datetime in the format

```
12 September, 2016
September 12, 2016
2016 September, 12
```

I need regex like it should return match in same order always for any dateformat given above

```
match-1 : 12
match-2 : September
match-3 : 2016
```

I need results in the same order always.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't switch the group order but you can name your groups:

```
(r'(?P<day>[\d]{2})(?:\s|,|\?|$)|(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?P<year>[\d]{4})')
```

- `(?P<day>[\d]{2})(?:\s|,|\?|$)`: matches a day, can be accessed in python with `l.group("day")`
- `(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)`: matches a month, can be accessed in python with `l.group("month")`
- `(?P<year>[\d]{4})`: matches a year, can be accessed in python with `l.group("year")`

Example:

```
import re

data = """
12 September, 2016
September 12, 2016
2016 September, 12
September 17, 2012
17 October, 2015
"""

rgx = re.compile(r'(?P<day>[\d]{2})(?:\s|,|\?|$)|(?P<month>[a-zA-Z]+)|(?P<year>[\d]{4})')

day = ""
month = ""
year = ""

for l in rgx.finditer(data):
        if(l.group("day")):
                day = l.group("day")
        elif(l.group("month")):
                month = l.group("month")
        elif(l.group("year")):
                year = l.group("year")

        if(day != "" and month != "" and year != ""):
                print "{0} {1} {2}".format(day, month, year)
                day = ""
                month = ""
                year = ""
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/4o0vfQ)

Answer (score 2):

Named groups as suggested below is a good way of doing it (especially if you already have the regexes set up) but for completion's sake here's how to handle it with the `datetime` module.

```
from datetime import datetime as date

def parse_date(s):
    formats = ["%d %B, %Y",
               "%B %d, %Y",
               "%Y %B, %d"]

    for f in formats:
        try:
            return date.strptime(s, f)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    raise ValueError("Invalid date format!")

arr = ["12 September, 2016",
       "September 12, 2016",
       "2016 September, 12",
       "12/9/2016"]

for s in arr:
    dt = parse_date(s)      
    print(dt.year, dt.strftime("%B"), dt.day)

"""

2016 September 12
2016 September 12
2016 September 12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python33/datetest.py", line 22, in <module>
    dt = parse_date(s)
  File "C:/Python33/datetest.py", line 19, in parse_date
    raise ValueError("Invalid date format!")
ValueError: Invalid date format!

"""
```

For more information, see the [datetime documentation page](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html).

Comment: You might want to cater for the case where data doesn't meet one of those three formats otherwise you'll risk getting a `NameError` - or potentially and even worse, re-using the previous date where the current one doesn't match...

Comment: Cool - alternatively - you can wrap it in a function like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581184)

Comment: That certainly looks a lot more elegant. I'm new to SO, should I just go ahead and use your idea in my answer or would it be more appropiate to let you submit it as an answer yourself?

Comment: You're fine as is :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change group orderings. You need to do a "or" of 3 patterns and then pass through the result to determine which group mapped to what, which should be pretty simple.