# Parsing date which may or may not contain milliseconds

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime

So this question is more of best way to handle this sort of input in python. Here is an example of input date `2018-12-31 23:59:59.999999`. The millisecond part may or may not be part of input.

I am currently using this code to convert this to datetime

```
input_ts = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_str, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
```

But the problem in this case is that it will throw an exception if input string doesn't contain milliseconds part i.e., `2018-12-31 23:59:59`

In Java, I could have approached this problem in two ways. (its a pseudo explanation, without taking into account of small boundary checks)

1. (preferred approach). Check the input string length. if its less than **19** then it is missing milliseconds. Append `.000000` to it.
2. (not preferred). Let the main code parse the string, if it throws an exception, then parse it with new time format i.e., `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S`
3. The third approach could be just strip off milliseconds.

I am not sure if python has anything built-in to handle these kind of situations. Any suggestions?

Comment: Why aren't you doing either #1 or #2?

Comment: I can. But since I am still learning Python and based on my past experience, python always have some super concise way to get things done. That's why I am asking

Answer (score 1):

You could use [python-dateutil](https://pypi.org/project/python-dateutil/) library, it is smart enough to parse most of the basic date formats.

```
import dateutil.parser
dateutil.parser.parse('2018-12-31 23:59:59.999999')
dateutil.parser.parse('2018-12-31 23:59:59')
```

---

In case you don't want to install any external libraries, you could iterate over list of different formats as proposed [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581184/8205106).

Answer (score -1):

```
from datetime import datetime # import datetime class from datetime package

dt = datetime.now() # get current time
dt1 = dt1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') # converting time to string
dt3 = dt2.strptime('2018/5/20','%Y/%m/%d') # converting a string to specified time
```

Comment: While this might answer the authors question, it lacks some explaining words and/or links to documentation. Raw code snippets are not very helpful without some phrases around them. You may also find [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) very helpful. Please edit your answer.