# Unknown strptime format handling python

Tags: python, datetime

I have the following problem. I am checking for an expiration date each time having a different format. One of them is '**Dec 31, 2019 12:00 AM**', other - '**2019-12-31 11:00**' and last (but I excpect more other values) - '**Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 EEST 2019**'. I am trying with ***datetime.strptime(dateToFormat, fmt).strftime("%Y%m%d")*** but if I need to pass all the fmt it will neve end as I don't know all the formats that could be received.

The showstopper for me is that I cannot use additional modules in python so I am currently stuck with the datetime module only...

Somebody has a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have a short list of potential formats, or could it be essentially any format?

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581128/how-to-format-date-string-via-multiple-formats-in-python

Comment: Yes, thank you very much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to format date string via multiple formats in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581128/how-to-format-date-string-via-multiple-formats-in-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you have clearly mentioned that you can use only `datetime` module of python! Incase if you have any option of using either `dateutil` or `datefinder` modules, you can use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9507648/datetime-from-string-in-python-best-guessing-string-format)

Comment: Yes, I used them before (the dateutil.parser) but I was forbidden :) Nevertheless, there is a useful suggestion in the answer you've provided me. Maybe finally I will use the "date_patterns" approach...
Thanks!