# pandas dataframe apply function with Value Error

Tags: pandas, apply

Have multiple tables need to process. One column of each table is date related but date format is changing, like 5/26, 05/26, 05/26/2020,05262020,5262020  I  used

```
  df[date] = df[date].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, dayfirst=dayfirst,
                                                         yearfirst=yearfirst)
```

It used to works just fine, but recently some tables in the date column might have strings like`"unknown"` or `"missing"` or `other strings`. Then I got an error it broke the process.

```
 "ValueError: Unknown string format"
```

How to handle this to exclude the rows I got

```
"ValueError: Unknown string format"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try ..except ...?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581128/how-to-format-date-string-via-multiple-formats-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Figure out a way to handle this, use regular expression first to exclude those rows then apply.

```
  df=df[df["date"].str.contains(re.compile('\d+'))]
  df[date] = df[date].apply(dateutil.parser.parse, dayfirst=dayfirst,
                                                     yearfirst=yearfirst)
```