# Convert multiple time formats in pandas series using to_timedelta()

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series of strings representing time values in different formats - these are track meet running times in various events.

There are 3 time formats in my series.  A sample looks like this:

| Times |
| --- |
| 1:50.24 |
| 1:51.88 |
| 49.35 |
| 13:58.97 |
| 2:39:05 |

I need to do math with these - I think I need to convert them to timedeltas.

When I try:
pd.to_timedelta(df['Times'])

I get

> ValueError: expected hh:mm:ss format before .

Is there a way to easily convert these strings into a common time datatype that I can do arithmetic with?

Comment: Might need to build a function like the following that deals with each case https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23581128/how-to-format-date-string-via-multiple-formats-in-python

Comment: Thanks for the link @le_camerone - I was wondering if this could be done more directly than having to deal with each case separately - but your link put me onto dateutil.parser which is helpful!