# Creating a program that prompts the user for a date, anno Domini, in month-day-year order, formatted like 9/8/1636 or September 8, 1636

Tags: python, exception

```
months = [
    "January",
    "February",
    "March",
    "April",
    "May",
    "June",
    "July",
    "August",
    "September",
    "October",
    "November",
    "December"
]

while True:
    user_input = input("Date: ")
    parts = user_input.split("/")
    if len(parts) == 3:
       
        month, day, year = parts
        try:
            month = int(month)
            day = int(day)
            year = int(year)
            if 1 <= month <= 12 and 1 <= day <= 31:
                break
        except ValueError:
            pass
    else:
       
        parts = user_input.split()
        if len(parts) == 3:
            month_name, day, year = parts
            try:
                month = months.index(month_name) + 1
                day = int(day.strip(","))
                year = int(year)
                if 1 <= month <= 12 and 1 <= day <= 31:
                    break
            except (ValueError, IndexError):
                pass

    print("Invalid date format. Please try again.")

print(f"{year}-{month:02}-{day:02}")
```

Here’s the code.

And the issue is when I input

```
September 8 1636
```

I should’ve got the invalid error but it’s reprompting, here’s the output

```
Date: September 8 1636
1636-09-08
```

#input of September 8 1636 results in reprompt expected program to reject input

its suppose to reject both input but it keeps reprompting

Here's the error I'm getting

```
:( input of September 8 1636 results in reprompt
    expected program to reject input, but it did not
```

so what can I do to fix it?

*Need help to fix this.*

Comment: Why would that date be invalid

Comment: The code's doing what you told it to do. There are no `/` in your input, so the `else` triggers, you split the date and get a month name `September`, you then grab the index from `months` for that string, add 1 to that, that's now a number between 1 and 12, so the code breaks out of the while loop. What part of that is _not_ what it should be doing?

Comment: You can use string method "endswith" to check if a string ends with a particular substring, e. g. a comma. "strip" removes given characters if they are there and returns the unmodified string otherwise.

Comment: I'll try to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you [use datetime for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23581184/13454049)?
You can try to parse multiple formats and formatting as a string is easy.

```py
from contextlib import suppress
from datetime import datetime, timezone

while True:
    date_string: str = input("Date: ")
    date: datetime
    for fmt in ("%m/%d/%Y", "%B %d, %Y"):
        with suppress(ValueError):
            date = datetime.strptime(date_string, fmt).replace(
                tzinfo=timezone.utc,
            )

            break
    else:
        print("Invalid date format. Please try again.")
        continue

    break

print(date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"))
```

Output:

```
Date: 9/8/1636                     
1636-09-08
```

```
Date: September 8, 1636
1636-09-08
```

```
Date: September 8 1636
Invalid date format. Please try again.
Date:
```